# sql Query Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table as shown below

```
Q_ID  DeptID  EmployeeName   City
100   100       testest      abcd
100   101         tata        cdd
```

with 100K records. I need a query which should fetch all records with same Q_ID but different DEPTID.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: so looking at this you want only 1 employee per department returned?  And can we assume there is no relation between Q_ID and DeptID?

Comment: Are you looking for records where a Q_ID is related to a specific DeptID?
Kind of like all records where Q_ID is equal to 100 and DeptID is equal to 101?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join it to itself:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.DeptID
FROM [MyTable] t1
INNER JOIN [MyTable] t2 ON t2.Q_ID=t1.Q_ID AND t2.DeptID>t1.DeptID
```

Comment: Should the '<>' be '>' or '<' to avoid the reflexive listing of each pair twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with analytic functions and thus avoid a join. In more situations than not, this will be more efficient, but it depends on the actual data and indexing.

```
with TRanked as (
  select
    QID,
    DeptID,
    EmployeeName,
    City,
    dense_rank() over (
      partition by CustomerID
      order by EmployeeID
    ) as ct
  from T
), TMaxRk as (
  select
    QID,
    DeptID,
    EmployeeName,
    City,
    max(ct) over (partition by CustomerID) as maxRk
  from TRanked
)
  select
    QID,
    DeptID,
    EmployeeName,
    City
  from TMaxRk
  where maxRk > 1;
```